# Gnome desktop freezes for some seconds when using NVIDIA Graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, xorg

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 in a new HP Omen 16 with

- AMD Ryzen 5800H (with an integrated graphics card)
- NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti

Problem: when resizing or moving windows, desktop freezes for ~10s, then continues as if nothing had happened, without any dialog suggesting to report a problem.

I have verified that his happens only while using the NVIDIA graphics card. If I choose to use the embedded graphics module in the AMD (completely deactivate the NVIDIA graphics card) there is no freeze.

Things I've tried:

- Upgrade nvidia drivers: completely remove and reinstall NVIDIA driver 510 (latest right now and "recommended and tested")
- Downgrade to driver 470
- Use Nouveau driver (open source): problem persists, and sometimes the computer will restart itself
- Upgrade to Linux kernel 5.15 and to latest (5.16.9): this provokes the NVIDIA drivers to stop working
- Downgrade to oldest kernel versions: this provokes the NVIDIA drivers to stop working

```
uname -a
Linux [...] 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

About NVIDIA

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8     6W /  N/A |    372MiB /  4096MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1016      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                186MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1358      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3467      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          141MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5370      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any more info needed please just ask

EDIT: if I start the computer with the HDMI external monitor connected, this problem does not happen even if I disconect it afterwards. However, if I start without external monitor and later connect it, the problem starts inmediatly.

Comment: Your edit suggests there's likely a problem that may have been corrected by a firmware update (UEFI) already.

Comment: Your grammar and title are not very clear. I would suggest editing them so that they make more sense.

Comment: No, it has not been corected

Comment: Ok @Jeff, I'll rewrite it, which parts do you find more confusing? English is not my native language, thanks for your comprehension

Comment: @Sanjo To make a more accurate translation from whatever language you natively speak, to English, to make it make more sense, you can, if you choose to, use Google Translate to help. Just a suggestion. I use it sometimes to translate English (my native language) to Spanish, because my Spanish is poor most of the time.

Comment: Hi @Jeff. I rewrote the question last week. Could you please take a look now? I hope now you'll understand it and you'll be able to give a constructive answer

Comment: @Sanjo It looks great now. Thanks!